# Android SSL works in Marshmallow but not nougat

Tags: android, ssl

Working on an app that says `Network Timeout` and logs `I/System.out: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer` when the app is opened. The login screen doesn't show until you click OK. If you type credentials and click login it give the same errors and repeats if you keep trying. It works fine in lower versions of Android but not 7 or 7.1 (nougat). I know some things changed and I've fixed some but I cant get past this. I've read some other post but didn't really understand. I'm not well versed in SSL and I didn't write this APP.

```
2277-4026/com.google.android.gms.persistent I/GoogleURLConnFactory: Using platform SSLCertificateSocketFactory
3970-4082/com.example.escojob I/System.out: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer
```

The cert gets created and stored on in a folder called MyDocuments. I've added permission checks to write files and it writes the files fine. I added `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"` to the manifest and created `network_security_config.xml`.

network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">mydomain.com</domain>
            <trust-anchors>
                <certificates src="system"/>
                <certificates src="user" />
            </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Here is SSLConnect.java.

SSLconnect.java

```
public class SSLConnect extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>> {
    private Activity activity;
    private String urlString;
    private final int timeoutTimeLimit = 10000;
    private String jsonMethodName;
    private boolean dialog;
    private boolean list;

    public SSLConnect(Activity activity, String urlString, 
            String jsonMethodName, boolean progressDialog, boolean list) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.urlString = urlString;
        this.jsonMethodName = jsonMethodName;
        this.dialog = progressDialog;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        ArrayList<String> listStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            URL json = new URL(this.urlString);
            HttpsURLConnection jc = (HttpsURLConnection) json.openConnection();
            jc.setConnectTimeout(this.timeoutTimeLimit);
            jc.setSSLSocketFactory(Variables.context.getSocketFactory());
            InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(jc.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input);

            String line = reader.readLine();

            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(line);

            if(!list){
                listStrings.add(jsonResponse.get(this.jsonMethodName + "Result").toString());
                return listStrings;             
            }
            else
            {
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonResponse
                        .getJSONArray(this.jsonMethodName + "Result");

                if (jsonArray.length() == 0)
                    listStrings.add("No results found");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    String toAdd = jsonArray.getString(i);
                    listStrings.add(toAdd);
                }
            }
            jc.disconnect();
            reader.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            timedOut = true;
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

        return listStrings;

    }

    Boolean timedOut = false;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        if (dialog) {
            mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this.activity, "Loading...",
                    "Data is Loading...");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> orderNumbers) {
        if (dialog) {
            try {

                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
        if (timedOut) {
            GUI.oneOptionDialog(activity, "Network Timed Out", "OK", true);
        }

    }
```

Comment: The problem is probably less the client code but that the server is incompatible to the modern TLS versions or ciphers used by Android 7. If you provide the URL of the server one can have a closer look.

Comment: That didn't cross my mind. 50.195.146.214 is the server. I wouldn't know how to check it.

Comment: esco-web.escocommunications.com is the name

Comment: I did an SSL check and it looks like it's using RC4... which got turned off. Do you know how to add modern Ciphers to server 2003 by chance.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#tls-ssl That link shows the requirements.

Comment: That system is really pretty badly configured and this is probably the cause of your problem. I have no idea how to properly configure server 2003 but I know that it is end of life since two years and should better not be used anymore. As for fixing the configuration please ask another question, because this is a server side problem which is different from the client side problem you asked in your question.

Comment: Sounds good. Thank you for leading me down the right path! Saved me hours of banging my head! I'll just suggest upgrading the server. It's really old anyway.

Comment: If you want too post an answer based on this I'll except it. You were right on the money.

Comment: I'm working on a case to get a new server but when I run the cert check [link](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=esco-web.escocommunications.com) it shows Android 7 compatible with TLS1.0. Am I missing something?

Comment: First you don't need to get a new certificate for the same domain but can use the existing one. Then, it's not only about the protocol version (TLS 1.0 vs. TLS 1.2) but about the ciphers supported. And specifying that a certificate is compatible with a specific Android version is just marketing, because certificate are independent of TLS protocol versions and mostly independent of supported ciphers.

Comment: I ran two patches on the server and did some registry edits rebooting after each step. 
Do them at your own risk.

[Link 1 is 1st Microsoft Patch/Fix 262679] https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/948963

[Link 2 is 2nd Microsoft Patch/Fix 192447] https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/948963


Here are the instructions below and the link. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3050509/improving-cipher-security-in-windows-server-2003-sp2 "This is the Link from Microsoft for full details Article ID: 3050509 from Mar 24 2015"

Comment: To cite myself: *As for fixing the configuration please ask another question, because this is a server side problem which is different from the client side problem you asked in your question.*

Comment: It's fixed. I was just showing how I fixed it.

Comment: Then very well.